# Getting information with JSON

Tags: c#, json

can someone explain me how to use JSON? I know it has something in common with XML but that is as much as I know.
I am trying to get all the names from this page [Link](http://bukget.org/api/plugins) and put them in a List so I can put them in a ListView.

Does anyone know how I should do this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? This is going to be pretty hard if you're not even sure what JSON is.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know where to start :(. And I just want to say: I'm willing to learn!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many alternatives to use Json

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string json = wc.DownloadString("http://bukget.org/api/plugins");
```

---

[DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

```
var ser1  = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<string>));
var list1 = (List<string>)ser1.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)));
```

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var list2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(json);
```

[Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) (My favorite)

```
var list3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

---

You can even use `dynamic`

```
dynamic list4 =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
string firstName = list4[0];
```

Comment: OMG! So simple?!! A thousand thanks :D! I've used your favorite: Json.Net ^^, it's very easy to use!

Answer (score 2):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a simple standardized way of communicating information between two computers using text strings. You will need to use a JSON library and that library should produce a object that you can use to populate your list.

See [json.org](http://json.org) for more information about the format and for links to libraries for c#

Comment: I have read that Jayrock is a good solution and am looking through the examples right now :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx) json library with C#, it is very simple.

I recommend you put the words of the [link](http://bukget.org/api/plugins) into a string and then try it to deserialized it to your class.

Check also the [Comparison of data serialization formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats), and the [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) wiki.